How Hindu scriptures address this issue of repeated transgression and atonement

What do scriptures say when someone uses atonement given in our smriti as a free pass to do wrong?


example: They eat meat, drink alcohol, and waste semen for self pleasure. They then realize they did something wrong, atone for it, and after a few months do the same thing again. This person continues in this cycle.


If someone has used atonement as a free pass for a long time in past, but now genuinely wants to change, how can he be forgiven for his actions?


What do scriptures say when someone uses atonement given in our smriti as a free pass to do wrong?
No method will work if the person commits his error again. He must stop completely.

‘Vyasa said, 'By penances, religious rites, and gifts, O Bharata, a
man may wash off his sins if he does not commit them again. By
subsisting upon only one meal a day, that procured by mendicancy, by
doing all his acts himself (without relying on the aid of a
servant)....by becoming a brahmacharin (celibate) and always ready for
exertion, by casting off all malice, by sleeping on bare ground, by
publishing his offence to the world, by doing all this for full 12
years, a person can cleanse himself from his sin ......'

Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section 36
If someone has used atonement as a free pass for a long time in past, but now genuinely wants to change, how can he be forgiven for his actions?
One can always start penance again but one must stop doing bad thing completely. Otherwise nothing will be gained.
